# Sending an image through JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api

noobie here hope you guys don't mind! Im trying to query my user/id/pictures.json but all it returns are attributes cus i did a generic format.json {render :json => @photo.to_json()}. My question is how can i create and encapsulate the actual data from the images, so my client can turn that data in to an image? And also what do i need to create(attribute wise) besides the path of image(say you only had useless attributes eg: height content_type, description, thumbnail file_name)?

this is what im trying in my index.json.erb so far

```
}
  <% @photos.each do |photo|%>
   data: <%= StringIO.new(Base64.encode64(photo.public_filename(:large))) %>
  <%end%>
}
```

i am getting back

```
{
 data: #<StringIO:0x1058a6cd0>

}
```

which is not the IMGdata im looking for
looking for

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [Data-URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).
They essentially are Base64-encoded entities (documents) formatted as a URI

```
[{ "name":"red dot", "data": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="}, ...]
```

**[UPDATE]**

You need to read the file and encode it as Base64 (you also need to strip the newlines away in rails 2.3.x)

```
data = ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(File.read("/images/image1.png")).gsub("\n", '')
uri  = "data:image/png;base64,#{data}"
```

Comment: got a quick question, after some googling i found that asset_data_uris might work in rails 3, but if i wanted to use rails 2 is there any options? I have the project up on both versions

Comment: shouldn't i be doing this first ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64("/images/image1.png")

Comment: Hey thnx alot!! really appreciated this one last question in my json do i send the uri or the raw data for my ios app to consume? or can i do both? which is less o a headache  ? THNX again!!!

Comment: so im basically doin this for my json right now, can i use this data in my ios app? 
{ "profile_pic ":<%= Base64.encode64(File.read("/Users/rui_y/connect_Me2/public"+ @user.avatar_photo_url(:thumb))).gsub("\n",'')%>,
   
}

Comment: That depends on how you will be using the images. If I remember correctly Cocoa (and presumably iOS/UIKit) handles Base64 encode images/data out-of-the-box. When you UI is HTML/CSS based the data-uri's will be more useful as you can just embed them as an image <img src="data:..." /> or a CSS background *{ background-image: url("data:..."); }

Comment: so i got the json to send but when i try to access the data value it comes back as null. here is my code "profile_pic":      
"<%= Base64.encode64(File.read('/Users/rui_y/connect_Me2/public'+ @user.avatar_photo_url(:thumb)).gsub("\n", '')) %>"
the json comes back as
"profile_pic":      "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcH
+p/Ob9Xrf6D8po/hOhI4U5SSm4Es8vUE/riYmJj2B0iefbkz/2Q=="

Comment: try this: "profile_pic": "<%= Base64.encode64(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'public', @user.avatar_photo_url(:thumb)[1..-1]))).gsub("\n", '') %>"

Comment: There's a `strict_encode64` method that does not append newlines every 80 chars. So there's no need for the gsub call.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Ruby on Rails, aren't you?

Then there are some steps needed to download an image (e.g. a png):

**Create a mime type**

Go to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` and insert `Mime::Type.register "image/png", :png` at the end.

**Create an image**

For example, you could use the gem Chunky_PNG to create an image, see at http://rubygems.org/gems/chunky_png and https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png/wiki

**Prepare your controller**

You have to tell your controller, that it can accept pngs. Modify your controller the following way

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :png

    def show
        # your own stuff
        # ...

        respond_with(response) do |format|
          format.json
          format.png do
            send_data ChunkyPNG::Image.new(width, height, ChunkyPNG::Color::TRANSPARENT), :type =>"image/png", :disposition => 'inline'
          end
        end
    end
end
```

This will create a fully transparent image. If you want to draw something in this, look at the Chunky PNG docs.

Comment: I forgot: In the URL you have to change the last ending ``.json`` to ``.png``

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the client how to render it really. This works for me, maybe worth a try.

```
  render json: @thumbnail, type: :jpeg, content_type: 'image/jpeg'
```